# Fill base class property by calling method to fill base class only once?

Tags: c#

I have 3 below classes :

```
public class Department
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { set; get; }
}

public class DeptCode100 : Department
{
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public string Prop4 { set; get; }
}

public class DeptCode200 : Department
{
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }
    public string Prop6 { set; get; }
}

public class Employee
{
  public void Process()
  {
   foreach (var employee in _employees)
   {
      if (employee.deptCode == 100) // 100
      {
         var deptCode100 = new DeptCode100();
         InjectDepartment(deptCode100,employee);
      }
      else if (employee.deptCode == 200)//200
      {
         var deptCode200 = new DeptCode200();
         InjectDepartment(deptCode200,employee);
      }
   }
}
 protected void InjectDepartment(Department dept,Employee emp)
 {
     dept.Prop1 = emp.Code;
     dept.Prop2 = emp.Basic;
 }
}
```

Now what I want to do is I want to call this InjectDepartment method only once instead of calling twice (because later on when I will have 3-4 subclass then I would have to call this method 4 times depending upon number of subclass) and pass different subclass based on the condition.

Comment: You don't call it in the provided code. please add the code you're talking about

Comment: Use constructor injection?

Comment: To which class `InjectDetpartment` method belongs to?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Updated my code

Comment: @millimoose Constructor injection means.Can you please provide more details

Comment: Are you sure, you know what you try to do here? DeptCode100 and DeptCode200 don't even have the right properties!

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya :i have added the class and updated the question

Comment: Make it static.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé :Sorry now i have fixed everything in the question

Comment: Well except that it's invalid code because you've got a `foreach` loop directly in a class declaration... please provide a [mcve].

Comment: (It's not clear what `DeptDetails` is, and you're not currently calling `InjectDetpartment` at all...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Because of network issue my update was not applying on the question but now its complete and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve - you don't use any of the properties from the subclasses, and you don't do anything with the newly-created objects after setting the properties. Once you've initialized the department, what are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at all possible, just initialise objects using constructors, this means they're fully formed the moment they're available to calling code; and makes it impossible for the initialisation to happen twice on any given object:

```
public class Department
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { set; get; }

    public Department(string prop1, string prop2)
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
    }
}

public class DeptCode100 : Department
{
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public string Prop4 { set; get; }

    public DeptCode100(string prop1, string prop2, string prop3, string prop4) : base(prop1, prop2)
    {
        Prop3 = prop3;
        Prop4 = prop4;
    }
}

public class DeptCode200 : Department
{
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }
    public string Prop6 { set; get; }

    public DeptCode200(string prop1, string prop2, string prop5, string prop6) : base(prop1, prop2)
    {
        Prop5 = prop5;
        Prop6 = prop6;
    }
}
```

You shouldn't need `InjectDepartment`, because you should be creating a `Department` when you have everything you need to create it:

```
// ...
if (employee.deptCode == 100)
{
    var dept1 = new Department100(employee.Code, employee.Basic, ...);
}
```

If you really don't know and can't know the values for `Prop3` etc. when constructing a `Department`, leave those out of the subclass constructors, and fill them in later.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but notice that Prop1 and Prop2 of department are getting value from employee i.e emp.Code and emp.Basic

Comment: @Learning: So pass those in when you call the constructor. Or better yet, change the constructors to accept `Employee` and fill them from there...

Comment: @Learning - I added an example of use. Passing `Employee` is also a good idea unless you for some reason don't want that coupling.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I'll give it a try:

```
protected void InjectDetpartment(Department dept,Employee emp)
 {
     if(dept is DeptCode100 dc1)
     {
         dc1.Prop3 = emp.Code;
         dc1.Prop4 = emp.Basic;
     }
     else if(dept is DeptCode200 dc2)
     {
         dc2.Prop5 = emp.Code;
         dc2.Prop6 = emp.Basic;
     }
     else
     {
         dept.Prop1 = emp.Code;
         dept.Prop2 = emp.Basic;
     }
 }
```